# Summation of factorial.

Tags: combinatorics, summation

$$2(\frac{1}{3!\times7!}+\frac{1}{1\times9!})+\frac{1}{5!\times5!}=\frac{2^a}{b!}$$ find $a,b$ by some predictions I see $b=10$ but what about numerator. I think we have to $\sum {N\choose r}=2^N$ but how?. Thanks.

Comment: I think one fast method to solve this is simply to work out the number of factors of 2 on each side.  Also, in the brackets, you can use $(1/a + 1/b) = (a+b)/(ab)$.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly write it as follows:

$$\frac{1}{1!\times9!}+\frac{1}{3!\times7!}+\frac{1}{5!\times5!}+\frac{1}{7!\times3!}+\frac{1}{9!\times1!}$$

$$=\sum_{n=0}^4\frac{1}{(2n+1)!(10-(2n+1))!}$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{10}\frac{1}{n!(10-n)!}$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{2^{10}}{10!}$$

$$=\frac{2^9}{10!}$$

Hence $a=9$, $b=10$.